# subquery mysql on Update in same table

Tags: mysql

I know some of you will hate me for asking, but i have this:

```
UPDATE `f.forums` 
   SET `order` = 66
     , forumHeader = (SELECT forumName FROM  `f.forums` WHERE id = 1) 
 WHERE `id` = 8
```

Clearly not working, i searched for 2 hour for questions and i get alot of inner join and stuff, but it not helping, i get the name from the same table..

i'm so out of option right now..

> i did leave SELECT forumName
>
> Try with join, unsuccessful for one reason or another
>
> i can handle this with a second $sql query in PHP but i know it can be done in one..

Comment: Hate is surely too mild an emotion to adequately convey the seething contempt which I fear unable to contain. Oh wait, try Ueerdo's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your ` use is (probably) incorrect should be `f`.`forums` (the . should not be inside unless the table name is actually `f.forums`.

2) You can't UPDATE a table with a subquery to itself.

I believe this would accomplish what you want though:

```
UPDATE `f`.`forums` AS f1, `f`.`forums` AS f2
   SET f1.`order` = 66
     , f1.forumHeader = f2.forumName
WHERE f1.`id` = 8 AND f2.id = 1
;
```

Comment: the name of of table is 'f.forums' it is correct :p
but very interesting the define twice the same table, i would never found this without your help! looks very simple but you need to have the brains to come with such answer

Thank you very much